# How to escape html <tag> inside of document.write function

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to paint the literal string of the HTML code inside of a tag on javascript i try to escape it but doesnt work.

```
function paint_string(n){
        document.write("'<table>'");
            for (i in rango(0,n)){
                document.write("'<tr><td></td></tr>'");
            }
        document.write("'</table>'");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the tag doesn't work`?

Comment: Are you trying to put a literal string of HTML on the page, or do you want a table?

Comment: Try using `document.createElement` instead: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

Comment: He needs to use `&lt;` and `&gt;` or `textContent`!

Comment: < with &lt; 
> with &gt;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many problems in your implementation.

1. You are surrounding your tags with `''`: `document.write("'<table>'");`
2. You are using `document.write()`, which is as dangerous as it can be.
3. You are splitting between tags opening and closing, which doesn't work in HTML.
   *When you put `document.write('<table>')`, browser autocompletes with `<table></table>`.*
4. Not sure what `rango(0, n)` is and how you are going to use it here.

What you need is to construct the HTML and update the `innerHTML` of a particular element.

```
function paint_string (n, el) {
  var finalHtml = '<table>';
  for (i in rango(0, n)) {
    finalHtml += '<tr><td></td></tr>';
  }
  finalHtml += '</table>';
  document.getElementById(el).innerHTML = finalHtml;
}
```

I have created a working snippet, that might work for your code.

```js
function paint_string (n, el) {
  var finalHtml = '<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%">';
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    finalHtml += '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>';
  }
  finalHtml += '</table>';
  document.getElementById(el).innerHTML = finalHtml;
}
paint_string(5, "hello");
```

```html
<div id="hello"></div>
```

---

Or if I understood your question correctly, you wanna put the text as HTML, then you need to do this:

```js
function paint_string (n, el) {
  var finalHtml = '<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%">\n';
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    finalHtml += '<tr><td></td></tr>\n';
  }
  finalHtml += '</table>\n';
  document.getElementById(el).textContent = finalHtml;
}
paint_string(5, "hello");
```

```html
<pre id="hello"></pre>
```

Comment: < with &lt; 
> with &gt;

Comment: @ymd_ Yes... You are right... I just commented it: You need to use `&lt;` and `&gt;` or `textContent`!

Comment: @ymd_ What I have given you is a `textContent` method. Don't use `document.write()` function.

Comment: It works, but i will keep my answer it was more simple. Thanks.

Comment: @ymd_ Sure... Definitely... `:D`

Answer (score 1):

I use `&lt;` for `"<"` and `&gt;` for `">"`.

```
function paint_string(n){
    document.write('&lt;table&gt;');
        for (i in rango(0,n)){
            document.write('&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;');
        }
    document.write('&lt;/table&gt;');
}
```

Comment: Also, don't forget the `;` at the end. Editing your answer. And you forgot the `'`s...

Comment: Do you know how to render a `/t` tab in HTML?

Comment: Use `&nbsp;` four times?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the single quote like:

```
function paint_string(n) {
    document.write("<table>");
    for (i in rango(0, n)) {
        document.write("<tr><td></td></tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table>");
}
```

Comment: Care to elaborate?